# refering to the next sublist in a single cycle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine that I have this sublists:

```
list=[["A","A"],["C","D"],["E","F"],["G","H"],["I","J"]]
```

I want to put an "X" in the second position of a sublist when they have the same letter (in this case, it would be the first sublist):

```
list=[['A','A'],['C','D']]
for i in list:
while i[0]==i[1]:
    i[1]="X"
print (list)
```

But, at the same time, I want that the elements from the sublists to the right advance 1 postion, in a way I dont actually replace the "X", but putting it in a blank space, like this:

```
list=[["A","X"],["A","C"],["D","E"],["F","G"],["H","I"],["J",]
```

The problem is that I need the sublists that are to the right in the same cycle. Like this:

First i=["A","A"]

Next i but in the same cycle=["C","D"]

How do I refer to the "Next i but in the same cycle"?

And how would you advance 1 position like that)

Comment: and how should look the output for this input `[["A","A"],["C","D"],["E","F"],["G","G"],["I","J"], ["J","H"]]` ?

Comment: it should look like this: [["A","X"],["A","C"],["D","E"],["F","G"],["X","G"],["I","J"],["X","J"],["H",]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Misunderstood initially. My solution would be to handle it as a string (although slightly more complicated as the solutions below):

```
#!/bin/python

lis=[["A","A"],["C","D"],["E","F"],["G","H"],["I","J"]]
st = ""
for item in lis:
  for a in item:
    st += a
i = 0
while i < len(st)-1:
  if st[i] == st[i+1]:
    st = st[0:i+1]+"X"+st[i+1:len(st)-i+1]
  i = i+2

print st

lis =[]
i = 0

while i < len(st):
  if i < len(st)-1:
    lis.append([st[i],st[i+1]])
  else:
    lis.append([st[i],])
  i = i+2

print lis
```

Comment: Are you sure this gives the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to merge all your sublists in a new list like this:

```
my_list = [["A","A"],["C","D"],["E","F"],["G","H"],["I","J"]]
new_list = [i for sublist in my_list for i in sublist]
```

Then, check if the element in `i` position is equal to the element in `i + 1` position, we insert `X` in `i + 1` position like below:

```
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    if new_list[i] == new_list[i+1]:
        new_list.insert(i+1, 'X')
```

The last step is the split the resulted list with step `2` (the 3rd argument of `range()`) as follows:

```
res_list = [new_list[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(new_list), 2)]
```

**Example of output:**

```
>>> res_list
[['A', 'X'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G'], ['H', 'I'], ['J']]
```

With `my_list = [["A","A"],["C","D"],["F","F"],["G","H"]]`, the result would be:

```
[['A', 'X'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'F'], ['X', 'F'], ['G', 'H']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with a bit of hard coding. May not suitable for large range of list as it takes more time. but may be helpful for basic understanding.

```
l=[["A","A"],["C","D"],["E","F"],["G","G"],["I","J"]]
print "given input :  ",l
for i in l:
    while i[0]==i[1]:
        i.insert(1,"X")
print "your output : ",l
ls = []
lx = []
for i in l:
    ls.extend(i)
print "extend the list :",ls

lx = [ls[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(ls), 2)]
print "final_output : ",lx
```

output:

```
given input :   [['A', 'A'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'G'], ['I', 'J']]
your output :  [['A', 'X', 'A'], ['C', 'D'], ['E', 'F'], ['G', 'X', 'G'], ['I', 'J']]
extend the list : ['A', 'X', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'X', 'G', 'I', 'J']
final_output :  [['A', 'X'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G'], ['X', 'G'], ['I', 'J']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to figure out what the value of `i` should be for the next index, the issue can be avoided completely by first flattening the list-of-lists into a single string of characters.

After that is done, the characters in this string can be accessed a pair-at-a-time and `'X'` characters added whenever the two characters in the pair are the same—then the pairs of the generated sequence can be turned back into sub-lists in the final result:

```
def pairwise(sequence):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s2,s3), (s4, s5), ..."
    for i in range(0, len(sequence), 2):
        yield sequence[i:i+2]

list1 = [["A", "A"], ["C", "D"], ["E", "F"], ["G", "H"], ["I", "J"]]

chars = ''.join(''.join(p) for p in list1)
gen = (''.join(p) if p[0] != p[1] else ''.join((p[0],'X',p[1]))
            for p in pairwise(chars))
result = [list(p) for p in pairwise(''.join(gen))]

print('result: {}'.format(result))
```

Output:

```
result: [['A', 'X'], ['A', 'C'], ['D', 'E'], ['F', 'G'], ['H', 'I'], ['J']]
```